# Oracle SQL Plus to summarize a table

Tags: sql, oracle

newbie to Oracle's SQL PL syntax.

I'm trying to summarize information on a specific table which I'm so far doing with ALL_TAB_COLUMNS.

BUT - I'm struggling to get three, pipe delimited, 'examples' (top 3 rows) of each column included in the SELECT statement. End table would look like so:
[image]

Query so far:

```
Select 
TABLE_NAME,
COLUMN_NAME,
DATA_TYPE,
(SELECT LISTAGG((Select Column_Name FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS WHERE table_name='TBLREFCOMPANY'), ' || ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY CONO) "Product_Listing"
    FROM tblRefCompany
    where ROWNUM <= 3)
FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS
WHERE table_name='TBLREFCOMPANY'
```

Comment: [SQL\*Plus](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqpug/SQL-Plus-quick-start.html) is a command-line interface for Oracle Database, not a GUI as shown in your screenshot. If *"Oracle's SQL PL syntax"* means [PL/SQL](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/lnpls/overview.html), that's a programming language and also not related to your question.

Comment: If you are trying to get data from the table as well as data from `all_tab_columns` in a single SQL query, that would be highly nontrivial.  You'd likely be looking at a pretty sophisticated XML query that would not be terribly easy to maintain (particularly for someone new to SQL).   If you can create new objects in the database, you could build a pipelined table function that would generate dynamic SQL internally to produce this output but I don't know whether that would work for you.

Answer (score 1):

`ALL_TAB_COLUMNS` doesn't quite look like screenshot you posted.

I *think* you need a simple concatenation, not aggregation. Something like this (see line #6):

```
SQL> select
  2    table_name,
  3    column_name,
  4    data_type,
  5    --
  6    owner || ' | ' || data_length || ' | ' || nullable as examples
  7  from all_tab_columns
  8  where table_name = 'EMP'
  9    and rownum <= 3;

TABLE_NAME COLUMN_NAME  DATA_TYPE    EXAMPLES
---------- ------------ ------------ ------------------------------
EMP        EMPNO        NUMBER       SCOTT | 22 | N
EMP        ENAME        VARCHAR2     SCOTT | 10 | Y
EMP        JOB          VARCHAR2     SCOTT | 9 | Y

SQL>
```

---

**[EDIT, as it looks that you don't need concatenation but aggregation, after all]**

```
SQL> select
  2    a.owner,
  3    a.table_name,
  4    --
  5    listagg(c.column_name, ' | ') within group (order by c.column_id) columns
  6  from all_tables a join all_tab_columns c on a.table_name = c.table_name
  7  where a.table_name = 'EMP'
  8    and c.column_id <= 3
  9  group by a.owner, a.table_name;

OWNER      TABLE_NAME COLUMNS
---------- ---------- ------------------------------
SCOTT      EMP        EMPNO | ENAME | JOB

SQL>
```

Comment: That was a poor example which only makes confusion. Why didn't you - as Stack Overflow directions suggest - post a proper test case: CREATE TABLE and INSERT INTO sample data (which makes the "source"), and then explain and present desired result? That would make it easier for people - who are trying to help - actually *help* (and not waste their time). I *tried* to compose another query which - I think - might be what you're looking for. Have a look. If it still isn't "it", do as suggested: post proper test case.